# ODE / Maximal solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading a book about differential equations and found something I couldn't understand, so could someone explain this concept to me?

> The solution to the Cauchy problem is defined only locally for $t$ in
>   a neighborhood of the initial time $t_{0}$. If a solution cannot be
>   extended beyond a certain time $T$ , two cases may arise:
>
> - The point $(t,x(t))$ approaches the boundary of the domain.
> - The solution blows up, i.e $|x(t)|$ approaches infinity.

I don't understand what that means. Does that mean we don't want to extend the solution in order to avoid those 2 cases happening?

---

Also, could someone explain to me the meaning of the maximal solution theorem and when we can use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Rephrased: if the solution to the Cauchy problem $x'=f(t,x)$ starting from the point $(t_0,x_0)$ cannot be extended beyond a time $T$, that means that either $\lim_{t \to T^-} (t,x(t))$ is on the boundary of the domain of $f$ or that $\lim_{t \to T^-} |x(t)|=+\infty$. The former is a somewhat unusual case. The latter is quite commonplace.

Comment: This is a theorem, so it has nothing to do with "what we want", nor does it care about our intentions. It says that if it's impossible to extend the solution beyond $t = T$, then this happens for one of  exactly two reasons. If these reasons do not apply, then it's possible to extend the solution further ... if we (or anybody else) so chooses.